# ViewController is blank after navigating away and returning

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an app where two view controllers share a UIView subclass as the main source of UI. It works perfectly when the app is starting, but if I navigate away from the initial view, and return to it, all of the UI is lost. What do I need to do to preserve the views UI post-navigation?

My app flow is: MainView -> TableView -> DetailView
Just going from Main to Table to Main itself makes the UI vanish.
(rank isn't 10 yet, so here's a link to view: https://gfycat.com/enormousanchoredindochinesetiger)

What I do is load the UI in the UIView class through `layoutSubviews`, and in the UIViewControllers I set the instantiate the class, UI in the `loadViews` method by saying `view = viewClass`. I've tried adding this (`view = viewClass`) to viewWillAppear() as well, but it does nothing.

I've also tried creating two unique view classes in case instantiating was a problem. It didn't change anything.

ViewController:

```
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = baseView
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        requestLaunchData()
        setButtonTargets()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        view = baseView
    }

    //How I push to the next view
    @objc func upcomingButtonTapped() {
        let vc = TableViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        vc.upcomingLaunches = upcomingLaunches
    }
```

UIView:

```
    class BaseView: UIView {

    //Lots of labels and buttons instantiated

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setUI() //adding subviews
    }

    //Layout configurations
    }
```

Before it was this structure, I had all the UI (labels, buttons, a map) directly created and configured in each ViewController, which made both massive. But, it also worked.

Comment: It seems like the first view disappears even **BEFORE** next view arriving. So I think you not mentioned the code that caused this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It definitely does that. There's nothing really special happening beyond what you see though. Nothing else affecting the view.

Comment: @TheRock You were right, it was happening elsewhere. My answer below explains the problem. Thanks for taking the time to look!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after a night's rest.

So here's how you need to use a custom UIView class as your ViewController's view:

```
class YourView: UIView {
    //Create your properties, views, etc. 
    let exampleView = UIView()

    override layoutSubviews(){
        super.layoutSubviews()

        addSubview(exampleView)

        //Add layouts, etc.
}
```

And then in your ViewController, in either viewDidLoad, or loadViews (like me here):

```
let customView = YourView()

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    view = customView //Sets the entire view to all the UI you created in the custom class
}
```

The FATAL mistake I made was this:

```
override layoutSubviews(){
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let sView = superview { //This gives you frame size and such
        sView.addSubview(exampleView)
    }
}
```

This sets the UI's memory to the SuperView, which gets lost the moment you leave that view, because of `view = customView`. So my controller was rendering `view = customView`, which was empty, because all the UI was set to the `superView` which was superseded by `customView`.

I hope that helps anyone trying to use this same architecture in the future.